# Can I put a figure in the header using memoir?

Tags: graphics, header-footer, memoir

I'm trying to put an image as a header but the first line of the text is overlapping the image as well as I could not put it on the first page.

[image]

Follow my commands:

```
\documentclass[article,11pt,twoside,a4paper,english,brazil,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{nomencl}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{microtype}

    \usepackage{lipsum}

\setulmarginsandblock{140pt}{\lowermargin}{*}   
\setheadfoot{5\baselineskip}{\footskip}         
\setheaderspaces{72pt}{*}{*}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}


\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/sober.png}}{} %% pagina par
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/sober.png}}{}  %% pagina ímpar ou com oneside
\makeheadrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 


\makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{Campinas - SP, 29 de julho a 01 de agosto de 2018.\\ \textit{SOBER - Sociedade Brasileira de Economia, Adminstração e Sociologia Rural}}{}   
\makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{Campinas - SP, 29 de julho a 01 de agosto de 2018.\\ \textit{SOBER - Sociedade Brasileira de Economia, Adminstração e Sociologia Rural}}{}  
\makefootrule{mystyle}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{1pt}  
\begin{document}
  \pretextual
   \pagestyle{mystyle}

\selectlanguage{brazil}

\frenchspacing 

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\singlespace
 \lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}


\textual
 \pagestyle{mystyle}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

How do I correct this overlap. I also wish the text does not end up too close to the footer (image below).

[image]

Here is the image header:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gb510qq3cbg7vl7/sober.png?dl=0

Thank you!

Comment: With the memoir class, you are supposed to call `\checkandfixthelayout` after setting margins, header and footer space, and such.

Comment: There is a weird command for the page style in this class. I would never use `abntex2` for articles. Using packages like `scrlayer-scrbase` and `fancyhdr` + `geometry` is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the `abntex2` class but I'm assuming from your question title that it might be based on the `memoir` class. The default page layout allocates one line to the header and footer. Use

```
\setheadfoot{<headheight>}{<footheight>}
```

to adjust these values.

As @remco says remember to call

```
\checkandfixthelayout
```

after all your layout changes to make sure that they are implemented and compatible with each other.